# Python support for NSTREAM?

Tags: python

Does NSTREAM (formerly know as SWIM) have Python support?
I can see the documentations and development in Java, but not on Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a developer advocate at Nstream. Currently, Nstream only has a client SDK for python. This allows for interacting with Web Agents, but not for implementing them. SwimOS is being ported to Rust so that language bindings can be provided for languages like Python. Python support via the Rust port is a critical item on the Nstream roadmap and is well underway.

Regards,
Fred

Answer (score 1):

After talking to a NSTREAM consultant, I found out that currently there is no (limited) development support for Python and all major development happens in Java.